# Effect on ping response when using Raspberry Pi as firewall (lag, jitter)

Tags: networking

I've been looking for some good information about using the Raspberry Pi as a simple home firewall / router / DHCP server, to separate my home network from the supplied ISP router.

I've seen [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/803/raspberry-pi-as-a-linux-firewall) on the Raspbery Pi StackExchange site

and even [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-_J2po3i0U%E2%80%8E)

and unfortunately none of the write-ups mention the lag that the Pi may introduce, even if it can cope with 5MBps traffic, and the ping times for the speedtest done in the video are relatively slow - 56ms - (my ping from ISP is typically 19ms to 29ms).  I wonder what his ping time was before using the Pi as a router?

Has anyone had any experience of the Pi slowing down ping response time when used as firewall / router?

Comment: The biggest problem is the USB to LAN chip. It can cause severe bottlenecks on high volume. pfSense is the perfect solution but you need to search how to get it to work on the Pi. Remember internet ping has nothing todo with the "Router". Pings are peer to peer connections that are resolved by your DNS provider. So if you have a firewall or not the ping will be the same (excluding traffic shapers)

Answer (score 1):

I use one for simple browsing and youtube and it hasn't had much of an effect.
Though I only had a couple of devices on at a time.
The lag will get worse with a higher CPU Load though.
Ping times seemed normal, however I'm using mine as a WiFi router, so ping times for me weren't a big issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the Pi with an USB to Ethernet converter and the IPFire firewall, http://wiki.ipfire.org/en/hardware/arm/rpi
I loaded up a couple of torrents, and got the throughput up to 36 Mb/s. I then did a couple of traceroutes to the ISP's DNS server, and the Pi only showed 1-2ms delay.
I just tried it while running SpeedTest.net, and always saw <1ms delay.